# Deployment of asp.net core 2 application using bitbucket pipeline

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, bitbucket

I'm trying to create automatically deployment on staging server when I commit on bitbucket master. 
It's ordinary linux server that I'm using for staging envs. 
Is there some way to use pipelines for deployment?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was googling, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: search also for jenkins, webhooks, bitbucket, CI/CD

Comment: Circleci is a great tool for CI/CD pipelines, it integrates with bitbucket